# I need a vertical disintegration shader for 2d sprite objects with Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, shader, sprite

I am making a **2D game** with Unity3D and I need disintegration shader **for sprites** like the following picture (the picture is horizontal, i need it vertical)

[image]

The shader should have the following possibilites:

1. It should desintegrate the image from one line upwards.
2. The line should be defined with a floating number variable, which I will pass to the shader, between 0 and 1. Zero means no disintegration (just a normal image) and 1 means full disintegration of the entire image.
3. The shader should also keep support for the unity illumination of sprites (because I am planning to have lights in my 2d game)

I am not good with shaders, I previously have written only basic ones with libgdx before, so can you help me or point me in the right direction, what I should do?

Comment: I imagine you can do this with a displacement shader and a grayscale texture for the parts you want to move, and by how much.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Dissolve_With_Texture) shader?

Comment: I have seen this shader before but it is dissolving the texture with another effect. I need it to dissolve with the effect as in the image above!

Comment: @Iggy Can you elaborate on your comment in more detail. And keep in mind that i need to slowly disintegrate the whole image in a top-down maner

Comment: Have a look at this asset https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/69765